# How to add 2nd input on the KeyPress Function?

Tags: c#

How to Add key press in ' if(count<= 3)' condition. in this code we have define that if the input length is less than 3 or equal to 3 consider the input as quantity and then again go for the input if the input length is greater than 3 then consider the input as item code and search from database and quantity that we have entered it first time.

```
   enter code here
private void SearchItem_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e){
        if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Enter){
           ItemLength = SearchItem.Text;
            int count = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < ItemLength.Length; i++)
            {
                count++;
            }
            else if (count <= 3)
            {
                string qtyvalue = ItemLength;
                SearchItem.Text = "1001";
                SearchItem.Focus();
                GetItemCode();
                SearchItem.Text = Itemcodes;
                    //if (count <= 3 )
                    //{
                    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(myconstring);
                    string query = "SELECT ItemCode, ItemDescription, SRate FROM ITEM WHERE ItemCode 
                   = @ItemCode ";
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ItemCode", SearchItem.Text);
                    //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ItemDescription", SearchItem.Text);
                    conn.Open();
                    // DataTable dt = new DataTable(query);
                    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    // da.Fill(dr);

                    if (dr.Read())
                    {
                        bool Found = false;
                        if (SaleItemList.Rows.Count > 0)
                        {
                            foreach (DataGridViewRow drrr in SaleItemList.Rows)
                            {
                                if (Convert.ToString(drrr.Cells[0].Value) == SearchItem.Text && drrr.Cells[1].Value == drr["ItemDescription"])
                                {

                                    drrr.Cells[2].Value = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt16(qtyvalue) + Convert.ToInt16(drrr.Cells[2].Value));
                                    drrr.Cells[4].Value = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt16(drrr.Cells[2].Value) * Convert.ToDouble(drrr.Cells[3].Value));
                                    Found = true;
                                    TotalAmount.Text = (from DataGridViewRow row in SaleItemList.Rows
                                                        where row.Cells[4].FormattedValue.ToString() != string.Empty
                                                        select Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[4].FormattedValue)).Sum().ToString();
                                    Clear();

                                }
                            }
                            if (!Found)
                            {
                                drr = dt.NewRow();
                                drr["ItemCode"] = dr.GetValue(0).ToString();
                                drr["ItemDescription"] = dr.GetValue(1).ToString();
                                drr["Qty"] = ItemLength;
                                drr["Rate"] = dr.GetValue(2).ToString();
                                drr["Amount"] = Convert.ToInt32(drr["Qty"]) * Convert.ToDouble(drr["Rate"]);
                                dt.Rows.Add(drr);
                                SaleItemList.DataSource = dt;
                                TotalAmount.Text = (from DataGridViewRow row in SaleItemList.Rows
                                                    where row.Cells[4].FormattedValue.ToString() != string.Empty
                                                    select Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[4].FormattedValue)).Sum().ToString();
                                Clear();
                                SearchItem.Focus();
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            drr = dt.NewRow();
                            drr["ItemCode"] = dr.GetValue(0).ToString();
                            drr["ItemDescription"] = dr.GetValue(1).ToString();
                            drr["Qty"] = ItemLength;
                            drr["Rate"] = dr.GetValue(2).ToString();
                            drr["Amount"] = Convert.ToInt32(drr["Qty"]) * Convert.ToDouble(drr["Rate"]);
                            dt.Rows.Add(drr);
                            SaleItemList.DataSource = dt;
                            TotalAmount.Text = (from DataGridViewRow row in SaleItemList.Rows
                                                where row.Cells[4].FormattedValue.ToString() != 
                            string.Empty
                                                                                                
                            select Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[4].FormattedValue)).Sum().ToString();
                            Clear();
                            SearchItem.Focus();
                        }
                    }
                
            }
        }


enter code here
```

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i < ItemLength.Length; i++) { count++; }` can be simplified to `count = ItemLength.Length;`

Comment: There is no `for - else` in C#